# how does javascript private variable work in prototype implementation

Tags: javascript, inheritance, closures, prototype

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff696765.aspx

this website shows an example

```
function Circle(radius) {
  this.getRadius = function() {
    return radius;
  };
  this.setRadius = function(value) {
    if (value < 0) {
      throw new Error('radius should be of positive value');
    }
    radius = value;
  };
}
```

vs

```
Circle.prototype.getRadius = function() {
  return this._radius;
};
Circle.prototype.setRadius = function(value) {
  if (value < 0) {
    throw new Error('radius should be of positive value');
  }
  this._radius = value;
};
```

and on the page it states

"However, in such case, we lose the luxury of having truly private members, and have to resort to other means such as denoting privacy through convention (underscored property names). What it usually comes down to is making a choice between having truly private members or having more efficient implementation."

how does using prototype this._ losing the luxury of "truly private" members?, does prototype.this not considered as the reference to self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a property on an object is visible to code in a function on the prototype object, it's visible to code *anywhere*.

Answer (score 2):

since the variable this._ is a property set on the Circle instance and so is accessible from the object.

```
var c = new Circle();
c.setRadius(100);
console.log( c._radius );//100
```

Therefore it's not a truly private variable but only by conventions that anything starting with _ should not be used externally.

Comment: i c, so there's no way of doing an instance variable without using this keyword, this._radius, if you do var _radius, it woulnd't do?

Comment: Nope instance variables must be defined on this. var _radius is a local variable local to the function where it's defined.